MassTransit IBusControl.StartAsync "Broker unreachable" Exception
I am using MassTransit (version 8.1.3).  We have 2 different RabbitMQ clusters, and I have been using one of them up until now.  Everything works well.  Now, that I have switched to a different cluster, I am unable to connect to a RabbitMQ server and I am seeing a Broker unreachable exception.
I am able to go to the url on my browser with the user name and password, but I am unable to reach it through code.
How can I tell how to fix this?  Do you have any articles that would explain why I may be able to connect through my browser but not my code?  Any articles that could explain the tools I would use to see what is happening under the hood?  What kind of questions do I need to ask my DevOps team as to the difference between the 2 clusters?
Here's My Code
Creation of the Bus
`IBusControl busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(x =>
{
x.Host(new Uri(rabbitHost), h =>
{
    h.Username(rabbitUserName);
    h.Password(rabbitPassword);
});

x.ReceiveEndpoint(rabbitQueue,
    e =>
    {
        e.Consumer<MyConsumerClass>();
        e.Bind<MyConsumerClass>();
    }
    );

});`
Starting of the Bus
    private static void StartBus(IBusControl bus)
{
    try
    {
        MessageSource.WriteLine(TestRunId, Guid.Empty, "Starting Bus", DeviceId, null);
        TaskUtil.Await(() => bus.StartAsync());
        MessageSource.WriteLine(TestRunId, Guid.Empty, "Started Bus", DeviceId,null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageSource.WriteLine(TestRunId, Guid.Empty, $"StartBus faied", DeviceId,ex);
        throw ex;
    }
}

I tried using a different user.  I was hoping that I would be able to get in, but I wasn't.
I tried passing in a cancellation token specifying timeout.
I tried adding /userName to the end of the url.
I tried changing the host and port this way...
x.Host(url, port,"", h =>{
    h.Username(rabbitUserName);
    h.Password(rabbitPassword);
});


no logs from rabbitmq anywhere?

I think that you either have a problem with access to RabbitMQ, or with the user. If there is no problem with one cluster, but there is with the second, it definitely means the problem is not in the code.

In addition... I wrote this powershell script which reads the queues and it works, so I really need to see what the script would be to create a connection.
Clear-Host
$plainCredentials = "$():$()"
$encodedCredentials = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($plainCredentials))
$authHeader = "Basic " + $encodedCredentials
[string]$rqUrlQueues = "$http://:/api/queues/"
Write-Host "reading queues"
$respQueues = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get -Uri $rqUrlQueues -Headers @{'Authorization'= $authHeader}
Write-Host "done"

I figured out why I wasn't able to connect.... my url had the port of 15672 specified.  This is the default UI port, so it explains why I was able to connect via my browser.  Port 5672 is the default API port.  When I switched it to 5672, it worked.
My original url didn't have the port specified in it, so it used the default.
